# How to change autoCompleteTextview items color background

Tags: kotlin, autocompletetextview

i am implementing a spinner using material autocompletetextview and i want to change the background color of  each item . here is what i've done , but still not working :

```
        binding.civiliteInput.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->
        Log.d("TAG", "fillInput: the item selected is :  "+parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString())

        if(parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString() == "Mr"){
            view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(),R.color.lagfo_color))
            Log.d("TAG", "fillInput: the item selected is :  Mr coleur lagfo")
        }else if (parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString() == "Mme"){
            view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(),R.color.rose_pale))
            Log.d("TAG", "fillInput: the item selected is :  Mme coleur lagfo")
        }else if (parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString() == "Mlle"){
            Log.d("TAG", "fillInput: the item selected is :  Mlle coleur lagfo")
            view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(),R.color.lagfo_color))
        }

        civilite=binding.civiliteInput.text.toString();
    }
```